# plotting a graph for 24 hours from a year data

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, matplotlib

I have a dataset of 100 households' electricity consumption over 8760 hours. I have managed to plot the load over the year quite easily. However, I'm struggling to plot a graph showing changes over the 24 hours in a day.

```
householdData = pd.read_excel('/content/drive/MyDrive/Diss/cleanedInputData/100households.xls')
householdData
print(householdData)
  Time  Affluent  Adversity  Affluent  Comfortable  \
0    2019-01-01 01:00:00     0.254      0.244     0.155        0.215   
1    2019-01-01 02:00:00     0.346      0.154     0.083        0.246
2    2019-01-01 03:00:00     0.309      0.116     0.085        0.220   
3    2019-01-01 04:00:00     0.302      0.158     0.083        0.226   
4    2019-01-01 05:00:00     0.181      0.171     0.096        0.246   
...                  ...       ...        ...       ...          ...   
8755 2019-12-31 20:00:00     1.102      0.263     2.157        0.209   
8756 2019-12-31 21:00:00     0.712      0.269     1.409        0.212   
8757 2019-12-31 22:00:00     0.398      0.274     0.073        0.277   
8758 2019-12-31 23:00:00     0.449      0.452     0.072        0.252   
8759 2020-01-01 00:00:00     0.466      0.291     0.110        0.203
```

I then set time as index by:

```
Energy= householdData.set_index('Time')
```

from this im able to resample to days like:

```
Daily_kWh= Energy.resample("D").sum()
Daily_kWh
```

I tried plotting the graph using

```
#load v time of year
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (16,5))
ax.plot(Energy,  label='Hourly consumption',color = 'blue')
ax.set_ylabel('Hourly consumption [kWh]',size=15, color='green')
ax.set_xlabel('Time',size=15)
```

however this gives me a graph over the year. If i was to try find a graph over 24 hours for the households, how would i please do that. I've also tried aggregating all the loads into one hourly load but just can't seem to plot an hour graph.

Many thanks

Screenshots of codes.

[100 households code to set index](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fwV2X.png)

[graph of loads over the the year](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NtmRB.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pandas group by hour sum by day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59102847/pandas-group-by-hour-sum-by-day)

Comment: The linked question is a little different. They're interested in a sum, not an average, so you'll want to change `sum()` to `mean()`. Also you may need to remove the day from the groupby in the answer.

Comment: Hi Nick, thanks for your help. The link provided doesn't really help as I cant even get the x axis to show 24 hours. i feel really lost especially as it sounds quite simple to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expanding on my comment, here's how you could use a Pandas groupby to get the data you want.

I don't have your data, so I found a temperature dataset, for which I'm going to plot the average temperature and humidity by time of day.

[Here's the dataset I used](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/kadenswarr/hourly-weather-data-in-denver?resource=download).

Here's what it looks like loaded into Pandas:

```
                      Time  Temperature  Humidity
0      2002-01-01 00:53:00           19        77
1      2002-01-02 00:53:00           10        56
2      2002-01-04 00:53:00           30        51
3      2002-01-05 00:53:00           25        75
4      2002-01-06 00:53:00           23        55
...                    ...          ...       ...
145228 2020-10-20 19:53:00           48        54
145229 2020-10-20 20:53:00           45        58
145230 2020-10-20 21:53:00           41        62
145231 2020-10-20 22:53:00           40        65
145232 2020-10-20 23:53:00           39        65

[145233 rows x 3 columns]
```

Then, to take the average of within each hour, I can do this:

```
>>> df.groupby([df['Time'].dt.hour]).mean()
      Temperature   Humidity
Time                        
0       45.139758  61.040073
1       44.355489  62.120536
2       43.644279  63.125041
3       42.980814  63.900926
4       42.384857  64.625889
5       41.944766  65.208037
6       42.516102  64.338728
7       44.873058  60.481653
8       48.414203  54.953592
9       52.384374  48.758011
10      55.970739  43.172095
11      58.780842  38.814699
12      60.822490  35.724901
13      62.124835  33.862946
14      62.674975  33.215253
15      62.398745  33.717377
16      61.015865  35.953561
17      58.330413  39.925785
18      55.110671  44.751569
19      51.954741  49.534688
20      49.630772  53.407487
21      48.090309  56.253261
22      46.992736  58.124319
23      45.985773  59.849793
```

For every observation in my dataset, it extracts the hour for each row, and groups all rows with the same hour together. Then, it takes an average within each of those groups.

I can then plot the data, using this:

```
df.groupby([df['Time'].dt.hour]).mean().plot()
```

[image: plot of temperature vs hour of day]